# Renting a basement suite out for income, that has a lower ceiling - Data on percentage of renters to consider this a deal breaker

Tags: investing, income, landlord, market-data, renter

I'm in the market to move out, and I'm eyeing bungalows, mostly those that are built in the 1950's and 1960's in Winnipeg, Canada. I'm wanting to live on the main floor and have a tenant occupy the basement, which I would not really have a need for otherwise. From what I've seen so far, they have about a 6 1/2 height between the floor and the joists in the basement. I would have to punch in a new window to meet egress, but It's a cost I'm willing to incur.

From some asking around a dozen of my peers, most would not be willing to put up with a lower celling, and it would be a deal breaker for them. So I'm wanting to do more research and hopefully get data for a wider sample size of people on willingness to rent a suite with a lower ceiling.

So my question is, are there any data sources / studies anyone can recommend on this?

Edit: My end goal is to assess how difficult it will be getting a renter in / what % of people will nope out, and I want some data to back it up. If there is a slim chance, I will probably have to reconsider the housing type I'm targeting.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This best source of data would be a local real estate agent. They can tell you about recent rentals for similar properties.

Comment: This isn't an answer and the Q has been closed, but before you even consider this, you need to research local laws about number of points of egress required for rental properties. Many locales require at least 2 ways to exit a rental property in case of fire, ruling out basement rentals unless you're on a hill and the basement has accessible windows. It's possible that this applies to all residences, not just rentals.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://clkapps.winnipeg.ca/DMIS/Documents/DocExt/BL/2015/2015.54.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at this: Currently, in Europe (France, UK, Germany…) the minimum is 2.20 m (so close to 7 1/2). There are nuances on how binding this is and where it is defined (in building codes, only for rental properties, etc.) but anything below that is generally not considered fit for housing. You may find people desperate enough to tolerate less but that seems relevant to your question.